# Convert a chr vector into a double vector in r

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I convert a data.frame that contains a chr vector to a vector with double numbers?

Data looks as follow:

```
> head(klima)
   category  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  Mai  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dez
1 MaxTemperatur  2,8  4,7  9,5 13,4 18,2 21,6 24,3 23,7 19,1 13,8  7,3  3,5
2 MinTemperatur -3,6 -3,1  0,2  3,0  7,4 10,5 12,5 12,3  8,9  5,4  0,4 -2,3
3    Temperatur -0,4  0,7  4,7  8,1 12,7 16,0 18,3 17,7 13,7  9,3  3,7  0,6
4            NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
5  Niederschlag   60   55   73   82  119  111  106  116   99   88   76   74
6            NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

I want to tidy up this dataset with dplyr and gather.

```
    klima.bern.tn <- klima.bern %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  filter(category=="Temperatur" | 
           category=="Niederschlag" | 
           category=="MaxTemperatur" |
           category=="MinTemperatur" ) %>%
  gather(month,value,-category,convert=TRUE)
```

This give the following structure of data:

```
> str(klima.tn)
'data.frame':   48 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ category: chr  "MaxTemperatur" "MinTemperatur" "Temperatur" "Niederschlag" ...
 $ month   : chr  "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" ...
 $ value   : chr  "2,8" "-3,6" "-0,4" "60" ...

> head(klima.tn)
       category month value
1 MaxTemperatur   Jan   2,8
2 MinTemperatur   Jan  -3,6
3    Temperatur   Jan  -0,4
4  Niederschlag   Jan    60
5 MaxTemperatur   Feb   4,7
6 MinTemperatur   Feb  -3,1
```

Now I would like to format the value data set as flollow, that I get 3 commas values after the comma.

```
> head(klima.tn)
       category month   value
1 MaxTemperatur   Jan   2,800
2 MinTemperatur   Jan  -3,600
3    Temperatur   Jan  -0,400
4  Niederschlag   Jan  60,000
5 MaxTemperatur   Feb   4,700
6 MinTemperatur   Feb  -3,100
```

How can I achieve that?

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Chris

Comment: Do you want to multiply `value` by 100?

Comment: you have to take extra care because you are using a comma as the decimal separator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823126/converting-data-frame-from-character-to-numeric-in-r-to-use-in-time-series-funct/31823405#31823405

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `as.numeric(myChars)` *usually* does the trick if R can figure what numeric values are represented in `myChars`. It's smart enough to realize that `as.numeric("1.5") == 1.5`.

You have the added complication that `1.5` is represented as `"1,5"`, which confused R. This can be quickly remedied with

```
newValues <- gsub(",", ".", klima.tn$value)
numericValues <- as.numeric(newValues)
```